# Regular expression not capturing expected groups

Tags: java, regex

I suppose group[1] should be "xyz" and group[2] should be 'ab' for this input string.

```
String p = "(.+)\\s(ab|cd|efg)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);

String str = "xyz ab";

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);

System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Comment: Thank you for this link, and I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `m.find()`

```
String p = "(.+)\\s(ab|cd|efg)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p,Pattern.DOTALL);

    String str = "xyz ab";

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);

    if (m.find()) { 
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

`find()` will Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Output :

```
xyz
ab
```

you can also call `m.matches();` before fetching group, instead of `if (m.find())` but it's a good practice to use `find()` or `matches()` with `if` to verify the match found